# Role authentication User/Admin

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I need to develop an athentication panel with role SimpleUser and Admin where only admin can create users when he login.
SimpleUser's username and password should be created by admin else he will not have access to his account.
I'm using Nodejs and Angular7 and mongoDB 
Any help about this?

Comment: If you have a question please formulate it according to the guidelines. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check out this boilerplate, full MEAN app: https://github.com/DavideViolante/Angular-Full-Stack